# Data on the number of cats and dogs kept as pets in Asia and Africa

Tags: data-request, demographics, africa, asia

I am looking for data regarding dogs and cats kept as pets in Africa and Asia.

Comment: Please [edit] your question: divided by/over what? As your question is formulated now, an answer with only 4 numbers would meet the requirements (*23 million cats and 45 million dogs in Asia, 31 million cats and 14 million dogs Africa*). Also: what year/epoch? What data format?

Answer (score 5):

This [Paper](http://s3.amazonaws.com/zanran_storage/www.wspa.org.uk/ContentPages/48536804.pdf)  provides tables of ownership estimates of dogs and cats for most world countries. There is a description of the collection methodology.